# Automating Google Earth to open and zoom to feature?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-pro

I've been tasked with creating a link in an excel spreadsheet that will initiate some basic automation in Google earth.

The specific task is to:

1. Check if Google Earth is open
2. Check if specific kmz is loaded
3. Open Google Earth and and kmz if needed
4. Zoom to specific feature in kmz

I've been digging around the web to see what I can find. Google Earth API seems close, but it's deprecated as of December and seems focused on embedding in web pages.

Is there any other way to script out a process involving Google Earth?

My users all have Google Earth Pro.

Comment: Flyto will get you to the location if you reference the .kml it will do all the steps you want automatically. https://code.google.com/p/kml-samples/source/browse/trunk/kml/NetworkLink/flyToView/flyToView.kml?r=81